# I'm making a paint and using Japanese names for characters, Are the honorific/royal titles redundant?

Tags: names, honorifics, titles

*Disclaimer: I'm learning Japanese language but my level is really low*

I took painting as a hobby and I want to use the characters names using Katakana and Kanji. The character I'm painting is Bowsette クッパ姫. The base name is Bowser or Kooppa - クッパ and at the end is added the kanji "hime" 姫 which I understand as "A women of royalty descent, equivalent to a princess in western terms". In my own words this is something like "Princess Bowser"

**I want to know if "Daimo Kooppa Hime - 大魔王 クッパ姫" is correct**. 大魔王 クッパ is a name that Shigeru Miyamoto gave Bowser when he created it and because of aesthetics from a design standpoint I came up with 大魔王 クッパ姫(in my own words this is something like "Great Demon Princess Bowser") which will really help me to fill out the space in my painting but I don't know if its actually correct because I think that 大魔王 and 姫, could be redundant/clash or put in simpler words "Maybe they can't be together".

But I want to make emphasis on the fact that it's female so that's why I want to add 姫 at the end. Pretty much like Shurayuki Hime - 修羅雪姫 - Lady Snowblood or Kingu Teresa Hime - キングテレサ姫- Booette (yields the most results for that characters in specific, which is also from Nintendo)

I'm adding 2 pictures

Here we see the female version of Bowser as 大魔王 クッパ

[image]

Here we see the female version of Bowser as クッパ姫

[image]

I trying to do my best when it comes to investigate for my art but due to my limited knowledge of the language and not knowing any person knowledgeable on Japanese, I'm seek of help and I'd appreciate it. I did some research here and google there and even though I learn some things it didn't answer my question.

I really want to make things that not only look cool but are grammatically correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(大)魔王 is a gender-neutral title, and you can find female 魔王 in Japanese fictional works (example [1](https://dic.pixiv.net/a/%E9%AD%94%E7%8E%8B%E6%A7%98%28%E3%82%B8%E3%83%A3%E3%83%92%E3%83%BC%E6%A7%98%E3%81%AF%E3%81%8F%E3%81%98%E3%81%91%E3%81%AA%E3%81%84%21%29), [2](https://dic.pixiv.net/a/%E9%AD%94%E7%8E%8B%28%E3%81%BE%E3%81%8A%E3%82%86%E3%81%86%29), [3](https://dic.pixiv.net/a/%E9%AD%94%E7%8E%8B%28%E8%BB%A2%E3%82%B9%E3%83%A9%29)). Thus, technically speaking, 大魔王クッパ姫 is perfectly correct. That said, most Japanese people recognize Bowser simply as クッパ, and few people remember his title is 大魔王.

The first image you posted is a [fanart](https://seiga.nicovideo.jp/seiga/im8554041) drawn in the style of [Bikkuriman stickers](https://www.pinterest.jp/shuixiv/bikkuriman-stickers/). (It's so good that I almost thought it was official!) Many characters in Bikkuriman had kanji titles, and I think that's why the little-known title, 大魔王, was intentionally added.

Note that the romaji of 大魔王 is *daimaō*, not *daimo*.